# Как устранить ошибку Pagespeed "Пассивные прослушиватели событий не используются для улучшения производительности при прокрутке"

Tags: javascript, jquery, события, touch-event

При оптимизации сайта с помощью [Google Pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) столкнулся с такой проблемой, [image: проблема Google Pagespeed] которая ведет [на страницу с пояснением](https://web.dev/uses-passive-event-listeners), что нужно использовать пассивный режим в событиях прокрутки колесика мыши и тач событий.

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', onTouchStart, {passive: true});
```

Я использую на сайте библиотеку [jquery.ui.touch-punch.js](https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/blob/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js), но не могу понять куда в нее поместить свойство `passive: true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогло [здесь код для WordPress](https://gist.github.com/seojacky/9ab1c367d914b695f450e18bc01d062f).

```html
//Пассивные прослушиватели событий не используются для улучшения производительности при прокрутке
//© Калинский Евгений aka seojacky (https://t.me/big_jacky)
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'script_passive_event_listeners', 99 );
function script_passive_event_listeners(){
    ?>
<script>
(function() {
  var supportsPassive = eventListenerOptionsSupported();  

  if (supportsPassive) {
    var addEvent = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;
    overwriteAddEvent(addEvent);
  }

  function overwriteAddEvent(superMethod) {
    var defaultOptions = {
      passive: true,
      capture: false
    };

    EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function(type, listener, options) {
      var usesListenerOptions = typeof options === 'object';
      var useCapture = usesListenerOptions ? options.capture : options;

      options = usesListenerOptions ? options : {};
      options.passive = options.passive !== undefined ? options.passive : defaultOptions.passive;
      options.capture = useCapture !== undefined ? useCapture : defaultOptions.capture;

      superMethod.call(this, type, listener, options);
    };
  }

  function eventListenerOptionsSupported() {
    var supported = false;
    try {
      var opts = Object.defineProperty({}, 'passive', {
        get: function() {
          supported = true;
        }
      });
      window.addEventListener("test", null, opts);
    } catch (e) {}

    return supported;
  }
})();
</script>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос задан давно, но вижу что тут ссылаются на мой gist. Я недавно исправил код в этом gist, так что лучше брать [обновлённый код по ссылке](https://gist.github.com/seojacky/9ab1c367d914b695f450e18bc01d062f).
Ну и тем у кого WordPress рекомендую мой плагин [Helper Lite for PageSpeed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/helper-lite-for-pagespeed/). Там эта функция внедрена .